# How does a quotient group (G/N for example) make the normal subgroup (N) the identity element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This has eluded me, and my professor didn't really explain it well. I understand that given that N is a normal subgroup, that G/N = gN such that g is in G. However I don't really see how this can make N the identity element of G/N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity element in $G/N$ is the class $eN$, which is simply $N$.

More generally, you can show that 
$$hN=eN \Leftrightarrow h \in N$$

This means that all elements in $N$, and only elements of $N$, become the identity in $G/N$.

Comment: Oh, so it's because when multiplying any element in N by the entire subgroup, N is the result, so therefore any nN is always just going to be N, and therefore any element of n is always going to return N when you multiply it together by the entire subgroup?

Comment: @user3491700 Exactly. Moreover, if $hN=N$, then since $e \in N$ you get $he \in hN=N$. This also gives you the converse of your statement.

Answer (score 1):

For G/N group (obviously quotient group) , elements would be like ‘Na’ where a ∈ G.

For an element to be identity its operation to any element of grip must be the same element. Here our operation is multiplication (in default case)

Let’s say (Na)N= N(aN) | associative law

```
           = N( Na)|N is normal subgroup I.e. Na=aN

           = (NN)a | associative law

           = Na.   | N is normal subgroup, so its multiplication to itself would be same.


We saw that multiple of Na to N is Na again ⇔ N is identity of G/N.
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because $gNg'N=gN$ if and only if $g'N=N$.